# Prolog - findall function

Tags: prolog

How can I use findall function in another function, I mean

```
subset(0, [], []).
subset(Len, [E|Tail], [E|NTail]):- succ(PLen, Len),(PLen > 0 -> subset(PLen, Tail, NTail) ; NTail=[]).
subset(Len, [_|Tail], NTail):- subset(Len, Tail, NTail).
```

This gives sublist of a list with N elements but I want to keep all result in a list,then I wrote

```
 result(N,List,Result):- findall3(Y,subset(N,List,Y),Result).
```

Howewer I get error, I am new in prolog, is this usage allowed or not, if not how can I obtain these sublist in a list, is there anyway?

Comment: Did you mean to type `findall3`? It's really `findall/3` which means it is called `findall` and takes 3 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You want is `findall`, not `findall3`.